# Using Data Driven Pages to display Attribute table values?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, data-driven-pages, dynamic-text

How can I show ID/page specific attributes on a map book project that has already been made?

I recently took over our GIS mapping duties for a former coworker who retired.  He had already made a map book project using python for Food plot plantings, but there are no Attributes listed on each map page.

I am working with ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.

Comment: Can you add more info?  ...such as the py script that generated the DDP output, whether you are able to open the mxd okay in 10.2, if you've checked the source data and whether this input is as expected by your script?  If it's just dynamic text, you should be able to check this in ArcMap.

Comment: I am not sure how to even find the script used to generate the data driven page output.  I have no problem opening the mxd in 10.2. source data seems fine...

Answer (score 3):

The Help page on [Using dynamic text with Data Driven Pages](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s900000039000000) ,
shows data driven pages and how you can created a dynamic piece of text based upon an attribute in the table.